# Swift NSCopying is empty after copy

Tags: swift

So I inherited this code. But I have a Teams class and I have a copy function. Let me show you the class first:

```
class Team: NSObject, NSCopying {
    struct Keys {
        static let sportsID  = "SportsID"
        static let stampId = "StampNumber"
        static let associationID  = "AssociationID"
        static let team  = "Team"
        static let conference = "Conference"
        static let latitude  = "Latitude"
        static let longitude  = "Longitude"
        static let GPSLatitude  = "GpsLatitude"
        static let GPSLongitude  = "GpsLongitude"
        static let backgroundColor  = "BackgroundColor"
        static let letterColor  = "LetterColor"
        static let isActive  = "IsActive"
        static let venueLocation  = "VenueLocation"
        static let city = "City"
        static let state = "State"
        static let stadiumCampus  = "StadiumCampus"
        static let letterName = "LetterName"
        static let backgroundImage = "BackgroundImage"
        static let homeStampImag = "HomeStamp"
    }
    
    var objectId: String = ""
    var sportsID: Int = -1
    var associationID: Int = -1
    var stampId: Int = -1
    var team: String = ""
    var conference: String = ""
    var stadiumCampus: String = ""
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    var radius: Double = 100
    var backgroundColorString: String = ""
    var letterColor: String = ""
    var letterName: String = ""
    var isActive: Bool = false
    var venueLocation: String = ""
    var city: String = ""
    var state: String = ""
    var backgroundImageId: Int = 1
    var backgroundImage: UIImage?
    var homeStampImag: PFFileObject?
    var stampImage: UIImage?
    var rotationAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: -120...160)
    var date: String = ""
    var timestamp: Date = Date()
    var data: [String: Any] = [:]
    var isHomeTeam: Bool = false
    
    init(data: [String: Any] = [:], radius: Double, objectId: String = "") {
        super.init()
        self.objectId = objectId
        self.sportsID = data[Keys.sportsID] as? Int ?? -1
        self.stampId = data[Keys.stampId] as? Int ?? -1
        self.date = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "StampIdDate: \(self.stampId)") ?? ""
        self.associationID = data[Keys.associationID] as? Int ?? -1
        self.team = data[Keys.team] as? String ?? ""
        self.conference = data[Keys.conference] as? String ?? ""
        self.stadiumCampus = data[Keys.stadiumCampus] as? String ?? ""
        self.latitude = (data[Keys.latitude] as? Double ?? 0.0) == 0.0 ? data[Keys.GPSLatitude] as? Double ?? 0.0 : data[Keys.latitude] as? Double ?? 0.0
        self.longitude = (data[Keys.longitude] as? Double ?? 0.0) == 0.0 ? data[Keys.GPSLongitude] as? Double ?? 0.0 : data[Keys.longitude] as? Double ?? 0.0
        self.letterName = data[Keys.letterName] as? String ?? ""
        self.letterColor = data[Keys.letterColor] as? String ?? ""
        self.backgroundColorString = data[Keys.backgroundColor] as? String ?? ""
        self.isActive = data[Keys.isActive] as? Bool ?? false
        self.venueLocation = data[Keys.venueLocation] as? String ?? ""
        self.city = data[Keys.city] as? String ?? ""
        self.state = data[Keys.state] as? String ?? ""
        self.radius = radius
        self.backgroundImageId = data[Keys.backgroundImage] as? Int ?? 1
        
        guard let stampImage = data[Keys.homeStampImag] as? PFFileObject else { return }
        self.homeStampImag = stampImage
        
        if self.venueLocation.isEmpty {
            self.venueLocation = self.team
        }
        
        if self.stadiumCampus.isEmpty {
            self.venueLocation = self.city + ", " + self.state
        }
        self.data = data
    }
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Team(data: data, radius: radius, objectId: objectId)
            return copy
    }
}
```

I init a team

```
 let team = Team(data: teamJson, radius: sport.radius, objectId: sportTeam.objectId ?? "")
```

then later on I copy that team

```
let newTeam = team.copy() as! Team
```

So im still learning this stuff but I would assume team and newTeam would be the same. But newTeam is all empty.

```
<Pass_Sports.Team: 0x105fdb4e0> #0
  - super: NSObject
  - objectId: "iY012BOok2"
  - sportsID: -1
  - associationID: -1
  - stampId: -1
  - team: ""
  - conference: ""
  - stadiumCampus: ""
  - latitude: 0.0
  - longitude: 0.0
  - radius: 100.0
  - backgroundColorString: ""
  - letterColor: ""
  - letterName: ""
  - isActive: false
  - venueLocation: ""
  - city: ""
  - state: ""
  - backgroundImageId: 1
  - backgroundImage: nil
  - homeStampImag: nil
  - stampImage: nil
  - rotationAngle: -31.274499700732946
  - date: ""
  ▿ timestamp: 2021-11-30 07:38:43 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 659950723.884164
  - data: 0 key/value pairs
  - isHomeTeam: false
```

Please let me know if I need to give you anything else to figure this out. BTW I did dump teamJson and it has all the elements filled. And as I said, if I dump **team** before the copy, all the data is there. Especially in the **data** attribute. But after the copy, thats all default data.

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason to use this *objective-c-ish* stuff?

Comment: If your original data is json why not use Codable (and a struct)?

Comment: As I said. This is a project I inherited that I have to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a private initializer from another object of your type and use that in the `copy(with:)` implementation:

```
private init(other: Self) {
    self.sportsID = other.sportsID
    // etc
    super.init()
}

func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
    Self(other: self)
}
```

PS: I don’t know if the `objectId` property has a policy in your code that should make the copy differ from the original or not, thus take that into account too.

PPS: your initializer has a guard statement that will return before the data property is set too, and you are calling `super.init()` before setting the properties. Thus your init could just be able to set the whole object to default values, hence it could never set the `data` property to a non empty value because of that early exit with the guard statement. Since I don’t know if modifying your init will introduce any side effects in other parts of your code, I suggested to use the additional private initializer that will be used by `copy(with)`only, instead of fixing your original init.